# Task 'ideaModule' not found in root project 'temp'

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have installed latest version of intellij idea and gradle. When I say

```
gradle ideaModule
```

I get an error

```
Mohitas-MBP:temp abhi$ gradle ideaModule

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'ideaModule' not found in root project 'temp'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug                                                                                                                        option to get more log output.
```

OK. so it seems that I have to install a plugin. But the question is that is there a central place where I can install the intellij plugin for gradle?

I googled and every information I found was for Gradle Plugin for IntelliJ. but I think I want information on IntelliJ plugin for gradle. (so other way round).

I don't want to go into UI and fill in a lengthy wizard to create a gradle project. Instead, I want to use gradle to create an IntelliJ project from the command line.

Makes sense? is it possible? Sorry if this is a newbee question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should just add

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

in your build.gradle file to be able to call the custom task.
see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html for more information about the plugin

*Edit for global configuration*

I know of 2 ways depending mainly if you care/need to share with scripts with others

1. If you do not have to share your script you can create a `init.gradle` script under *userhome/.gradle/init.gradle*. This script is executed for all projects. You can then add `apply plugin: 'idea'` to this script so you can run the task for every project you create.
2. If you have to share the script with others, you can create a grade script and push it on a server. In your upcoming build file you will do
   `apply from: 'http://<path to shared gradle script>'`

In your case for this task, I think 1. is your best option.

Comment: Can I do this in one central place? or should I do this in each and every project which I am going to build?